# Easiest way to copy a directory recursively creating 0-length files

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I need to copy a file/directory structure recursively but without copying file contents (creating 0-length files). Is there any way to do that without custom scripting?

Windows 7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do exactly what you're asking: (**edit**: no it does not!)

```
xcopy <source dir> <destination dir> /T /E /O
```

**Edit**: This should be closer to what you're looking for:

```
robocopy <source dir> <destination dir> /E /CREATE
```

Robocopy should come with Windows 7.
Let me know if I got it right this time. :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at that more but currently none file is created, only directory structure is copied.

Comment: @Pavel Vlasov You're right, that command will not create 0-length files like you asked, I missed that requisite. Sorry.

Comment: @Pavel Vlasov I have edited my answer adding a different solution.